# How to set up django-social-auth for website authentication

Tags: django, facebook, authentication

Is there any easy and fully documented way of configuring django-social-auth(https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth.git)?The documentation is so incomplete.Templates are missing and what's up with all urls?

Comment: There is an example project that shows exactly what to setup. Which part are you having trouble with? https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/tree/master/example

Comment: It took me 5 hours to really understand the documentation but my app is working fine now.thanks

Answer (score 2):

First you have to generate de url where the user clicks, in args you put the url of the callback:

```
    args = {
        'client_id': settings.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        'scope': settings.FACEBOOK_SCOPE,
        'redirect_uri': request.build_absolute_uri('/authentication_callback'),
    }

    HttpResponseRedirect('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?' + urllib.urlencode(args)
```

The code for the callback:

```
    token = request.GET.get('code')

    args = {
            'client_id': settings.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            'client_secret': settings.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
            'redirect_uri': request.build_absolute_uri('/authentication_callback'),
            'code': token,
    }
    # Get a legit access token
    target = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' + urllib.urlencode(args)).read()
    response = cgi.parse_qs(target)
    access_token = response['access_token'][-1]

    # Read the user's profile information
    fb_profile = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%s' % access_token)
    fb_profile = json.load(fb_profile)

    # These is the info of the facebook account:
    first=fb_profile['first_name']
    last=fb_profile['last_name']
    email=fb_profile['email']
    fb_id=fb_profile['id']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: While this is solid information on FB authentication is has nothing to do with configuring django-social-auth.